# issue with treating grayscale values as a mask

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have this project that takes in images, converts it to grayscale and then finds edges in the images, and then adds the color back to it but in a blurred form so as "Cartoonify an image". I don't know why but about 60% times, the project is not able to detect lines and returns he same image back. I thought it can be problem with image but the program works with images of same characteristics and doesn't work with the same characteristics.
Doesn't work:
[image]
works:[image]

Note: The doesn't work image may appear to be working ok-ish. But for pictures taken from my camera, it is not able to detect line as like it is shown in 2nd row-3rd column.

Here is the Code, please help.

```
import cv2 #for image processing
import easygui #to open the filebox
import numpy as np #to store image
import imageio #to read image stored at particular path

import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

top=tk.Tk()
top.geometry('400x400')
top.title("Cartoonify Project!")
top.configure(background='white')
lablel = Label(top, background='#CDCDCD', font = ('calibri', 20, 'bold'))

def upload():
    ImagePath = easygui.fileopenbox()
    cartoonify(ImagePath)

def cartoonify(ImagePath):
    originalmage = cv2.imread(ImagePath)
    originalmage = cv2.cvtColor(originalmage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    #print(image)  # image is stored in form of numbers

    # confirm that image is chosen
    if originalmage is None:
        print("Can not find any image. Choose appropriate file")
        sys.exit()

    ReSized1 = cv2.resize(originalmage, (960, 540))
    #plt.imshow(ReSized1, cmap='gray')


    #converting an image to grayscale
    grayScaleImage= cv2.cvtColor(originalmage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ReSized2 = cv2.resize(grayScaleImage, (960, 540))
    #plt.imshow(ReSized2, cmap='gray')


    #applying median blur to smoothen an image
    smoothGrayScale = cv2.medianBlur(grayScaleImage, 5)
    ReSized3 = cv2.resize(smoothGrayScale, (960, 540))
    #plt.imshow(ReSized3, cmap='gray')

    #retrieving the edges for cartoon effect
    #by using thresholding technique
    getEdge = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(smoothGrayScale, 255, 
        cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9)

    ReSized4 = cv2.resize(getEdge, (960, 540))
    #plt.imshow(ReSized4, cmap='gray')

    #applying bilateral filter to remove noise 
    #and keep edge sharp as required
    colorImage = cv2.bilateralFilter(originalmage, 9, 300, 300)
    ReSized5 = cv2.resize(colorImage, (960, 540))
    #plt.imshow(ReSized5, cmap='gray')


    #masking edged image with our "BEAUTIFY" image
    cartoonImage = cv2.bitwise_and(colorImage, colorImage, mask=getEdge)

    ReSized6 = cv2.resize(cartoonImage, (960, 540))
    #plt.imshow(ReSized6, cmap='gray')

    # Plotting the whole transition
    images=[ReSized1, ReSized2, ReSized3, ReSized4, ReSized5, ReSized6]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,2, figsize=(8,8), subplot_kw={'xticks':[], 'yticks':[]}, gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1))
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
        ax.imshow(images[i], cmap='gray')

    save1=Button(top,text="Save cartoon image",command=lambda: save(ReSized6, ImagePath),padx=30,pady=5)
    save1.configure(background='#364156', foreground='white',font=('calibri',10,'bold'))
    save1.pack(side=TOP,pady=50)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add example images for both success and failure cases to better describe the goal and the issue

Comment: Try viewing the image after each step to see where its going wrong.

Comment: I have added the images, please check them

Comment: issue is `cartoonImage = cv2.bitwise_and(colorImage, colorImage, mask=getEdge)`. wrong function to achieve your goal.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you, do suggest any other methods that you believe may work?

Comment: use `cv2.subtract`

Comment: ok so i can pass the same image as the parameter and then retrieve the foreground, thanks for the idea. i you can post an answer, i would definitely check mark it. Thanks a lot, i just got a brilliant idea.